# cannot access file from its url in views django

Tags: django, django-views

I cannot access file from its URL in views Django but I can access it from templates in html files

```
def add_record(request):
if request.method=="POST" and request.FILES['record_file']:

 
    title = request.POST.get("title")
    record_file = request.FILES["record_file"]

    record= Record(title = title, record = record_file)

    record.save()


    sound = AudioSegment.from_file(record.record.path, format='m4a')
    octaves = 0.35

    new_sample_rate = int(sound.frame_rate * (2.0 ** octaves))
    hipitch_sound = sound._spawn(sound.raw_data, overrides={'frame_rate': new_sample_rate})
    hipitch_sound = hipitch_sound.set_frame_rate(44100)
    



    record.save()
```

I tried a lot of things but it did not work for me

[code in the views.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IKji.png)

[error that appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSuUu.png)

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see this question named [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Please [edit] the question and include code fragments.

Comment: You should work with `record.record.path`, not `record.record.url`.

Comment: thanks for your respond but i when i tried it  it gives me this error FileNotFoundError at /add_record
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Have you add media to your urls ?

Comment: yes i have added media to my urls

Answer (score 0):

hey I think you are trying upload from a form. please check your header content-type, is it **multipart/form-data** or any other. if not please make it as below

```
headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but my form already has this header

Comment: can you please add your form

Comment: it upload the file from the form to database normally and i can use the file at templates also but the problem after i upload the file i need to make processes on it so the problem in views.py